# Where to download gene list of human genome?

Tags: human-genetics, gene

I am looking for a place where I can download a full gene list of human genome. Either by HGNC symbol or ensemble ID as long as it is usable on the consensusPathdatabase. Up until this point I have only found fasta files which include a bit too much information and unfortunately not in the format I would like. I am not in the biology field myself so if I am asking for something unreasonable call me out on it!

Reason for this is I am trying to stress test an application that uses the output tabular forms from the gene set analysis tool on consensusPathbase. The stress test on the entire human genome seemed to be the best option as a bigger data set than that will probably not occur.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database you are looking for is ensembl [[Yates (2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkv1157)].

Go [here](http://www.ensembl.org/downloads.html) and chose  **Customise your download**. There you can select a **dataset** (e.g. genes and then specify human genes - currently uses build GRCh38; you can also go the same way [here](http://grch37.ensembl.org/downloads.html) to do the same for hg19/GRCh37).

After chosing your dataset, you can click on **Attributes** to specify what to include in your download (HGNC symbols, IDs, regions, GO terms, and a ton of other stuff), click on **Filters** to apply filters to your choices (only genes from a chromosome, region, and a ton of other stuff).

Then click **Results** and download your selection in a format of choice.

(Hint: click **Count** first and use it as a a sanity check to see if the number of selected genes fits your expectation.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help!